# rspec request specs failing when run from emacs using rspec-mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, rspec

When I run certain rspec request specs from emacs using rspec-mode I receive the following error:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _system_free
  Referenced from: /Users//.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

When I run the same spec from the command line it runs just fine. Wondering if anyone might know the reason as to why the error message occurs when running the rspec request specs through emacs?

Comment: Your question is poorly structured, but it's an important issue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by forcing emacs to use bash shell instead of zsh as suggested on the homepage of the rspec-mode project. I am copying that information here:

If you use ZSH and RVM, you may encounter problems running the specs. It may be so that an older version of Ruby, than the one you specified in .rvmrc, is used. This is because ZSH runs a small script each time a shell is created, which modifies the $PATH. The problem is that it prepends some default paths, such as /usr/bin, which contains another ruby binary.

What you can do to solve this is to use BASH for running the specs. This piece of code does the job:

```
(defadvice rspec-compile (around rspec-compile-around)
  "Use BASH shell for running the specs because of ZSH issues."
  (let ((shell-file-name "/bin/bash"))
    ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'rspec-compile)
```